# Stripping payload from a tcpdump?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, tcpdump, scapy

Is there an automated way (either in tcpdump or via a helper app Out There) to generate a pcap file that contains only Ethernet, IP and Layer 4 (TCP in my case) headers, so that there is no payload/application data in the resulting pcap? I've found that since header sizes often vary, it's impossible to pick a capture size that won't catch any payload data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can strip out the TCP payload very easily with Python's [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) module

**BEFORE**

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee tshark_wd]$ tcpdump -n -r sample.pcap 
reading from file sample.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
00:25:42.443559 IP 192.168.12.237.1052 > 192.168.12.236.22: Flags [P.], 
    seq 2445372969:2445373021, ack 1889447842, win 63432, length 52
00:25:42.443607 IP 192.168.12.236.22 > 192.168.12.237.1052: Flags [.], 
    ack 52, win 65535, length 0
00:25:42.443980 IP 192.168.12.236.22 > 192.168.12.237.1052: Flags [P.], 
    seq 1:389, ack 52, win 65535, length 388
```

**PAYLOAD STRIPPING**

Running this as root in linux...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
INFILE = 'sample.pcap'
OUTFILE = 'stripped.pcap'
paks = rdpcap(INFILE)
for pak in paks:
    pak[TCP].remove_payload()
wrpcap(OUTFILE, paks)
```

**AFTER**

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee tshark_wd]$ tcpdump -n -r stripped.pcap 
reading from file sample.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
00:25:42.443559 IP truncated-ip - 52 bytes missing! 192.168.12.237.1052 
    > 192.168.12.236.22: Flags [P.], seq 2445372969:2445373021, 
    ack 1889447842, win 63432, length 52
00:25:42.443607 IP 192.168.12.236.22 > 192.168.12.237.1052: Flags [.], 
    ack 52, win 65535, length 0
00:25:42.443980 IP truncated-ip - 388 bytes missing! 192.168.12.236.22 
    > 192.168.12.237.1052: Flags [P.], seq 1:389, 
    ack 52, win 65535, length 388
```

In the `tcpdump` above, notice the "XX bytes missing!" messages.  That is because we have removed the TCP payload.

Answer (score 1):

If simple truncate would work for you, you could use:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 96 -w test1.pcap
```

Later on you can analyze it with wireshark.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP is correct, there is no way to reliably predict the length of the TCP headers, due to the TCP Options field.  For the most part, that is the only part of the IP / TCP headers that has a significant chance of differing in length.  A fixed snaplen value does not guarantee that you always truncate the TCP payload in the correct place.

Answer (score -2):

My solution was as follows. I'd love to hear how others do it without external libraries or truncation. I'd love to hear how others performed this, because I was unable to find the remove_payload() function in the Scapy documentation, making this answer unusable.

```
#read pcap file 
pkts = rdpcap("packet-capture.pcap")

#write packet with payload "XXXXXXXXXX"
for pkt in pkts:
     pkt.load = "XXXXXXXXXX"

#write new pcap
wrpcap("new.pcap", pkts)
```

The problem with this is that, when read with tcpdump, it leaves a *bytes missing!* for the src IP. I can verify the infromation is still there using scapy via

```
pkts[_packet_num].load
```

Is there a way to regenerate the whole capture so it looks as if it was unaltered?

Comment: This sounds more like another question than an answer. Perhaps consider [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another.